# Can I send a custom json payload from the salesforce einstein bot?

Tags: salesforce-einstein

I need to enter some json in the bot, which it will send to the user on a certain utterance. This feature is available in google dialogflow es where you can add a custom payload in the responses field. Is there any way to implement it in salesforce einstein

I've tried to send it from the apex, maybe I'm implementing it in the wrong way.